# iOS MusicSequence: MusicPlayerStart() failed, return error code: -66720

Tags: ios, musicsequence

I searched this error code, that means *kAudioToolboxError_NoTrackDestination*.

I want to know how to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "audio" of background mode must be allowed, or MusicTrackDestinationCreate will return this error.